# I have created a blank project in react native and now I am trying to run it on my phone but it is throwing up this error

Tags: react-native

I have not made any changes to the code until now. I am just trying to run the project on my mobile but it is throwing this error.
[image: Error image]

Comment: try run `npx react-native start` then open your app

Comment: It seems to be an react/react-native version mismatch.

What is react-native-cli version?
How did you create the project?